# Hamiltonian Matroids

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matroid-theory

Similar to graphs, a Matroid $M$ is said to be Hamiltonian if there is a base $B$ of $M$ and $e \in M-B$ such that $B + e$ is a cycle of $M$. Is there any literature on this?

EDIT: Actually my interest is in finding literature  on matroids with the following property:

Both $M$ and $M^*$ are Hamiltonian and they share a Hamiltonian cycle i.e. there is $C$ which is a Hamiltonian cycle of both $M$ and $M^*$

Are there any characterization of such matroids?

Comment: Did you try http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22hamiltonian+matroid%22 ? It seems to answer your question "yes": there is literature (about 8 papers) on this. Or did you have a more specific question that these papers don't answer?

Comment: Actually, I would like to find out if there is a characterization of Matroids $M$ with a set $C$ Hamiltonian circuit simultaneously in $M$ and $M^*$. Maybe I should make my question more specific.